# Wrong date generated with new Date() Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I want to create a new Date with the following code:

```
 let date = new Date(dateComponents[2], dateComponents[1] - 1, dateComponents[0]);
```

Whereby `dateComponent` is:

`[ '10', '01', '2019' ]`

but when I:

```
 console.log(date);
```

I get:

`2019-01-09T23:00:00.000Z`

Why is it not:

`2019-01-10T00:00:00.000Z`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you don't state a time and timezone, JS uses midnight, local time. Our time is GMT+1, so the result will end up one hour less. Fix: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/82ex19u3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's about your timezone.

```js
let dateComponents = [ '10', '01', '2019' ]
let date = new Date(dateComponents[2], dateComponents[1] - 1, dateComponents[0]);
date.setTime( date.getTime() - date.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000 );
console.log(date.toISOString()); // 2019-01-10T00:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: You have reproduced the behavior OP is asking how to fix...

Comment: @ChrisG I didn't realize I posted the code without timezone line. Sorry about it.

Comment: @westdabestdb try `console.log(dates.toISOString())` and see result

Comment: You need to subtract the offset.

Comment: Done, thank you. @ChrisG

Comment: There is no need to mess with the timezone, just use [*Date.UTC*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC). Even using the timezone offset, you can use `date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - date.getTimezoneOffset())`.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the value passed to the Date constructor are treated as local. If you want the values to be treated as UTC, use the [Date.UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) method:

```js
console.log( 
  new Date(Date.UTC('2019', '01' - 1, '10')).toISOString() 
);
```